# Query each line of a multiple line text area

Tags: explode, lines

This fails when dealing with 2n `$line` when doing a query 'isbn' field. But it works perfectly if I query 'id' field. I have tested data using data strictly from the table. Any idea why is this happening? Or how can I debug this?

```
$massife = $this->Massives->patchEntity($massife, $this->request->getData());
$massiveTable = \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('MassiveErrors', array('table' => 'massive_errors'));
$lines = explode("\n", $massife->data);
$documents = $this->loadModel('Documents');
foreach($lines as $line){
    $document = $documents->find('all')->where(['isbn' => $line]);
    $row = $document->first();
    $massiveError = $massiveTable->newEntity();
    if(!empty($row)){
    $massiveError->document_id = $row->id;
    $massiveTable->save($massiveError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be using:

`preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/',$massife->data)`

instead of:

`explode("\n", $massife->data)`